# Why the slider plugin show before it is ready to generate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I use the jquery slider plugin "slippry" :

http://slippry.com/

I followed the tutorial and write like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#item').slippry();
            });
        </script>
```

And Html

```
        <ul id="item">
            <?php
            foreach ($banner_list as $key => $banner) {
                echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href='#slide'" . $key . "><img src='" . site_url("banner/" . $banner["image_url"]) . "'></a>";
                echo "</li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

The problem is , there is a second that the slider show when it is not ready.

[image]

And in a second , it is generated and show like this

[image]

Also ,  if I press f5 then it will not have this problem (perharps cached?) but when I press the enter at address bar to enter the page again it has the same problem again. How to fix the problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#item').slippry();
     $('#item').show();
});
```

and

```
#item{
    display:none;
}
```

---

To prevent reflow(page jumps up and down until images load) make a container for `#item` and apply the following css

```
#item{
        display:none;
        padding-bottom:30%;
    }

#item-container{
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

#item img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
    }
```

See [**how to prevent reflow**](http://andmag.se/2012/10/responsive-images-how-to-prevent-reflow/) for further details